# Question on computing $U_{xx}$

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I was reading page 38 of this  [article](http://www1.maths.leeds.ac.uk/~kersale/Teach/M3414/Notes/m3414_1.pdf).

How come be that answer at the top page 38.
Isn't

$$U_{xx} ={\partial U \over \partial \xi }.{\partial ^2 \xi \over \partial x^2 }  +{\partial \xi \over \partial x }.{\partial ^2U \over \partial x \partial\xi  }+.{\partial U \over \partial \eta  } .{\partial ^2 \eta \over \partial x^2}+{\partial ^2U \over \partial x \partial \eta }.{\partial \eta\over \partial x }  $$

What I did was I computed $U_x$ using chain rule and differentiated it again with respect to x

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\newcommand\d{\partial}$You want to use the chain rule so that $u$ itself is only partially differentiated by $\xi$ and $\eta$, not directly by $x$. For example
$$
\frac{\d^2 u}{\d x\d\xi} = \frac{\d}{\d x} \frac{\d u}{\d\xi} = \frac{\d^2 u}{\d\xi^2}\frac{\d\xi}{\d x} + \frac{\d^2 u}{\d\xi\d\eta}\frac{\d\eta}{\d x}.
$$

From
$$
\frac{\d u}{\d x} = \frac{\d u}{\d\xi}\frac{\d\xi}{\d x} + \frac{\d u}{\d \eta}\frac{\d \eta}{\d x}
$$
you obtain
\begin{align}
\frac{\d^2 u}{\d x^2}
&= \frac{\d}{\d x} \left( \frac{\d u}{\d\xi}\frac{\d\xi}{\d x} + \frac{\d u}{\d \eta}\frac{\d \eta}{\d x} \right) \\
&= \frac{\d}{\d x} \left( \frac{\d u}{\d\xi}\frac{\d\xi}{\d x} \right) + 
   \frac{\d}{\d x} \left( \frac{\d u}{\d \eta}\frac{\d \eta}{\d x} \right) \\
&= \left( \frac{\d}{\d x} \frac{\d u}{\d\xi} \right) \frac{\d\xi}{\d x}  + 
   \frac{\d u}{\d\xi} \left( \frac{\d}{\d x} \frac{\d\xi}{\d x} \right) + 
   \left( \frac{\d}{\d x} \frac{\d u}{\d\eta} \right) \frac{\d\eta}{\d x}  + 
   \frac{\d u}{\d\eta} \left( \frac{\d}{\d x} \frac{\d\eta}{\d x} \right) \\
&= \left( \frac{\d^2 u}{\d\xi^2} \frac{\d\xi}{\d x} + \frac{\d^2 u}{\d\xi\d\eta} \frac{\d\eta}{\d x} \right) \frac{\d\xi}{\d x}  + 
   \frac{\d u}{\d\xi} \frac{\d^2\xi}{\d x^2} + \\&\qquad
   \left( \frac{\d^2 u}{\d\eta\d\xi}\frac{\d\xi}{\d x} + \frac{\d^2 u}{\d\eta}\frac{\d\eta}{\d x} \right) \frac{\d\eta}{\d x}  + 
   \frac{\d u}{\d\eta}  \frac{\d^2\eta}{\d x^2} \\
&= \frac{\d^2 u}{\d\xi^2} \left( \frac{\d\xi}{\d x}\right)^2  + \frac{\d^2 u}{\d\xi\d\eta} \frac{\d\eta}{\d x} \frac{\d\xi}{\d x}  + 
   \frac{\d u}{\d\xi} \frac{\d^2\xi}{\d x^2} + \\&\qquad
   \frac{\d^2 u}{\d\eta\d\xi}\frac{\d\xi}{\d x} \frac{\d\eta}{\d x}  + \frac{\d^2 u}{\d\eta}\left( \frac{\d\eta}{\d x}\right)^2  + 
   \frac{\d u}{\d\eta}  \frac{\d^2\eta}{\d x^2} \\
&= \frac{\d^2 u}{\d\xi^2} \left( \frac{\d\xi}{\d x}\right)^2 + 2 \frac{\d^2 u}{\d\xi\d\eta} \frac{\d\eta}{\d x} \frac{\d\xi}{\d x} + \frac{\d^2 u}{\d\eta}\left( \frac{\d\eta}{\d x}\right)^2 + \frac{\d u}{\d\xi} \frac{\d^2\xi}{\d x^2} + \frac{\d u}{\d\eta}  \frac{\d^2\eta}{\d x^2}.
\end{align}